# Help identifying a tool?

Tags: tools

[image]

Anyone know what this is? We have two of them. The long notched piece moves up and down. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

It's a ladder jack. The square brackets go on the legs of an extension ladder and the hook goes over a higher rung. You can hang a staging plank between two ladders in the resulting triangle, which is why you have a pair of them.

The drawing below is backwards, but representative of the general idea. The jacks would normally be hung under the ladder so the plank is close to the building.

[image]

Comment: @AndrewLeach only thing it misses is the 2x4 to put between them, I can see all the parts needed. The upper hooks are folded back on themselves.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Ah. The hooks pivot on what look like rivets. I'll remove my earlier comment as potentially confusing.

Comment: Here's a [somewhat shakey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25Sh_5-UQq4) YouTube of these in use, and crucially, which way around the jacks should be mounted...